# Explicitly overriding constructors in ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3

All,

I ran into this funny thing in a different post.  It was pointed out to me that you can explicitly override a constructor... which doesn't seem necessary, and I am a little surprised it even compiles.  Take a look:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public function TestClass() {}
}

public class TestClass2 extends TestClass
{
    public override function TestClass2() {}
}
```

Explicitly calling override on the constructor might just be a no-op, as it is certainly not necessary.  **My question**: Is there a subtlety here that I am missing?  Does explicitly overriding the constructor tell the compiler something?

Comment: Interesting, I had no idea. Unless there's any difference however, this just adds to the number of characters written unfortunately.

Comment: @macke: certainly.  If there is a reason to use it, then I would consider it in those cases... but if there is no benefit, then I wouldn't use it either.  Only confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it's just a bit of freedom provided by as3 syntax :)
imho bytecode of an swf with overriden contstructor is equal to one of swf with a normal one

Answer (score 2):

```
public class TestClass
{
    public function TestClass() {}
}

public class TestClass2 extends TestClass
{
    public override function TestClass2() {
       super();//this makes call to the default constructor
}
```

Comment: But specifying the override keyword is not necessary.  Does override specify adm ything here?